# EF is not saving the current UserID and Date to database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Could someone please examine the code below and tell me why UserId and Date fields are not populating?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RecordCard(WeightViewModel vModel)
{
    Weight Model = vModel.Weight;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities())
        {
            Weight weight = new Weight();
            weight.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            weight.Stone = Model.Stone;
            weight.Pound = Model.Pound;
            weight.Date = System.DateTime.Now;

            db.Weights.Add(Model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

After I post the table Weight has a new record with Stone and Pound values but the UserId and Date are Null.

I have included below the Weight class for data references:

```
public partial class Weight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Stone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Pound { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you do this:

```
db.Weights.Add(Model);
```

instead of this:

```
db.Weights.Add(weight);
```

This is a **very good reason** to have `ViewModel` classes that *are not* your `DomainModel` classes. If the `ViewModel` were a different `Type` the `Add` to the database context would have failed with a compilation error.